# C: Huffman Encoding

Tags: c, huffman-code

I need to to write a function that's part of a system to use huffman encoding on a string. This particular function scans a string and then produces a list of singleton huffman trees based on the characters in the string. However, when I run it, this function doesn't do anything. Can anyone help me figure out what's wrong with this function?

```
hufflist* build_hufflist(char* s)
{
    char* letters = malloc(strlen(s));
    int x;

    int letterspos = 0;
    hufflist* output = malloc(sizeof(hufflist));
    output = NULL;

    char* scopy = strdup(s);
    make_capital(scopy);

    for(x = 0 ; x < strlen(s) ; x++) {
        if(('a' <= scopy[x]) && (scopy[x] <= 'z')) {
            scopy[x] -= 32;
        }

        if(char_in_array(letters, s[x] == 0)) {
            letters[letterspos] = scopy[x];
            letterspos++;
            hl_insert(output, huff_singleton(scopy[x], char_count(scopy, scopy[x])));
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```

char_in_array is a function that returns whether a character is in an array, and char_count returns the number of times a character is in an array. I've tested both of them and they work.

Also, here are the relevant data definitions

```
typedef struct leaf leaf;
typedef struct node node;
typedef struct huff huff;
typedef struct hufflist hufflist;

enum huff_tag { LEAF, NODE };

struct leaf {
    char c;
    int n;
};

struct node {
    int n;
    huff *lsub;
    huff *rsub;
};

union huff_union {
    leaf leaf;
    node node;
};

struct huff {
    enum huff_tag tag;
    union huff_union h;
};

struct hufflist {
    huff* val;
    hufflist* next;
};
```

Comment: You set the output to NULL right after mallocing it, that looks suspicious

Comment: Actually it looks VERY bad.

Comment: You have a nonstandard datatype and 2 functions that work on that datatype that you haven't defined for us.  That makes it very hard to determine where things go wrong.  Have you tried running it through a debugger?

Comment: Doesn't `make_capital(scopy);` do the same as `if(('a' <= scopy[x]) && (scopy[x] <= 'z')) scopy[x] -= 32;` in the loop immediately after?

Comment: You use `make_capital()` and `char_in_array()`. Are you aware that `string.h` makes `strupr()` and `strchr()` available? Although, I don't think Linux has `strupr()`.

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few issues that I spot.

1) You malloc `letters`, and then start using it without initializing the data to which it points to any base case (e.g. - all 0's, or a copy of `s`, etc.).  If, instead, `letterspos = 0` is meant to indicate that `letters` is empty, then `char_in_array()` will likely need that information too.

2) You malloc `output`, but then immediately set it to NULL and eventually return that.

3) You call `make_capital()` on `scopy` and then perform similar logic inside your loop.

4) You pass a boolean (0 or 1) to `char_in_array()` for its second parameter.  You likely intended to have the `== 0` outside your call to `char_in_array()`.

4a) The function `char_in_array()` only takes a pointer to `letters` and a character to check against.  It doesn't take `letterspos` for example.  So, the "end" of `letters` has to be embedded in the array itself (for example with a nul-terminator see 1)) or you need to pass `letterspos` too.

```
hufflist* build_hufflist(char* s)
{
    char* letters = malloc(strlen(s));  // 1) maybe calloc(strlen(s), 1) or calloc(256, 1) instead?
    int x;

    int letterspos = 0;
    hufflist* output = malloc(sizeof(hufflist));
    output = NULL;  // 2) probably not what you intended

    char* scopy = strdup(s);
    make_capital(scopy);

    for(x = 0 ; x < strlen(s) ; x++) {
        if(('a' <= scopy[x]) && (scopy[x] <= 'z')) {  // 3) didn't make_capital() already do this?
            scopy[x] -= 32;
        }

        if(char_in_array(letters, s[x] == 0)) {  // 4) should the == 0 be outside the call to char_in_arrays? 4a) doesn't char_in_array need letterspos too?
            letters[letterspos] = scopy[x];
            letterspos++;
            hl_insert(output, huff_singleton(scopy[x], char_count(scopy, scopy[x])));
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```

**EDIT** It looks like your code repeatedly scans the entire string (i.e. - you call `char_count()` for each new character you find), which is not optimal.  You can get a count of all the characters in the string in a single pass like so:

```
unsigned int char_counts[256] = { 0 };
unsigned char *ptr = (unsigned char*) scopy;

for (; *ptr; ++ptr)
  ++char_counts[*ptr];
```

`char_counts` now contains the count of each character contained in `copy`, indexed by the (unsigned) character value itself.  Characters not contained in the string will have a count of zero.  So then you could do:

```
for (x = 0; x < 256; ++x)
  if (char_counts[x])
    hl_insert(output, huff_singleton(x, char_counts[x]));
```

I'm assuming the order of the inserts doesn't matter, which may or may not be true.